# Blog post creation interface

Tags: mongodb, npm, blogs

I am building a custom blog using mean stack when i am done learning it as a first challenge. I want to create a page where i crate the posts with bold and italic text editing etc. Is there a npm interface or something that allows me to save the post as an entry in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

Textangular is the solution i found.